# How does the batch file detect if a given project has EJB3 interfaces?

Tags: batch-file, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I will like to create a JAR file with the stubs for a project because I will access the service through an external Java Client.

createEJBStubs serves me well in that regard

> For many client-side scenarios, the WebSphere® Application Server
>   Just-In-Time (JIT) deployment feature dynamically generates the
>   RMI-IIOP stub classes that are required for invocation of remote EJB
>   3.x business interfaces. However, there are some scenarios where the JIT deploy environment is not available to dynamically generate these
>   classes. In these scenarios, the createEJBStubs command must be used
>   instead to generate and embed the client-side stub class files in your
>   client application. If your client environment is one of the
>   following, use the createEJBStubs command: "Bare" Java Standard
>   Edition (SE) clients, where a Java SE Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is
>   the client environment. A WebSphere Application Server container (web
>   container, EJB container, or application client container) from a
>   version earlier than version 7, or without the Feature Pack for EJB
>   3.0 applied. Non-WebSphere Application Server environments.

I know that one of the issues one might face when executing this command is -

> The createEJBStubs command is not supported for use with a 2.x or 1.x
>   EJB module packaged inside a stand-alone JAR file. The stubs for a 2.x
>   or 1.x EJB module packaged inside a stand-alone JAR file must be
>   generated using the EJBDeploy tool instead. If the createEJBStubs
>   command is run against a 2.x or 1.x EJB module packaged inside a
>   stand-alone JAR file, then the command issues a CNTR9241I message, and
>   does not generate any stubs.

**How will the script determine if the arg provided(JAR) to the script contains interfaces which are of Type EJB3?**

The batch file is available at *%WAS_HOME%\bin\*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createEJBStubs uses the same logic as is used when analyzing JARs inside an EAR file.  If the JAR file contains ejb-jar.xml, then the version is checked from there.  Otherwise, if the JAR file contains a component-defining annotation (`@Stateless`, `@Stateful`, `@MessageDriven`), then it is an EJB version 3+ JAR.  Otherwise, it is not an EJB JAR file.

(You used the `ejb-3.0` tag and `websphere-8` tags, but WebSphere Application Server v8 implements EJB 3.1, so `@Singleton` would also qualify as a component-defining annotation.)